# Looping through XML Object PHP

Tags: php, xml

This is frustrating me! It seems so simple but I can't loop through this XML for the life of me. I'm getting back a SimpleXMLElement Object from this link (http://www.nfl.com/liveupdate/scorestrip/ss.xml). I'm trying to drill down into g array and get the attributes of [0], [1], [2] and etc. I'm just learning PHP. So any help would be appreciated.

The code I have tried:

```
$nfl = simplexml_load_file('http://www.nfl.com/liveupdate/scorestrip/ss.xml');
    foreach ($nfl as $game) {
        print '<pre>';
        print_r($game); 
        print '</pre>';
    }
```

It outputs:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [w] => 2
            [y] => 2014
            [t] => R
            [gd] => 1
            [bph] => 103
        )

    [g] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [eid] => 2014091100
                            [gsis] => 56186
                            [d] => Thu
                            [t] => 8:25
                            [q] => F
                            [h] => BAL
                            [hnn] => ravens
                            [hs] => 26
                            [v] => PIT
                            [vnn] => steelers
                            [vs] => 6
                            [rz] => 0
                            [ga] => 
                            [gt] => REG
                        )

                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [eid] => 2014091400
                            [gsis] => 56187
                            [d] => Sun
                            [t] => 1:00
                            [q] => F
                            [h] => BUF
                            [hnn] => bills
                            [hs] => 29
                            [v] => MIA
                            [vnn] => dolphins
                            [vs] => 10
                            [rz] => 0
                            [ga] => 
                            [gt] => REG
                        )

                )

            [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [eid] => 2014091401
                            [gsis] => 56188
                            [d] => Sun
                            [t] => 1:00
                            [q] => F
                            [h] => CAR
                            [hnn] => panthers
                            [hs] => 24
                            [v] => DET
                            [vnn] => lions
                            [vs] => 7
                            [rz] => 0
                            [ga] => 
                            [gt] => REG
                        )

                )

            [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [eid] => 2014091402
                            [gsis] => 56189
                            [d] => Sun
                            [t] => 1:00
                            [q] => F
                            [h] => CIN
                            [hnn] => bengals
                            [hs] => 24
                            [v] => ATL
                            [vnn] => falcons
                            [vs] => 10
                            [rz] => 0
                            [ga] => 
                            [gt] => REG
                        )

                )

            [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [eid] => 2014091403
                            [gsis] => 56190
                            [d] => Sun
                            [t] => 1:00
                            [q] => F
                            [h] => CLE
                            [hnn] => browns
                            [hs] => 26
                            [v] => NO
                            [vnn] => saints
                            [vs] => 24
                            [rz] => 0
                            [ga] => 
                            [gt] => REG
                        )

                )

            [5] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [eid] => 2014091404
                            [gsis] => 56191
                            [d] => Sun
                            [t] => 1:00
                            [q] => F
                            [h] => MIN
                            [hnn] => vikings
                            [hs] => 7
                            [v] => NE
                            [vnn] => patriots
                            [vs] => 30
                            [rz] => 0
                            [ga] => 
                            [gt] => REG
                        )

                )

            [6] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [eid] => 2014091405
                            [gsis] => 56192
                            [d] => Sun
                            [t] => 1:00
                            [q] => F
                            [h] => NYG
                            [hnn] => giants
                            [hs] => 14
                            [v] => ARI
                            [vnn] => cardinals
                            [vs] => 25
                            [rz] => 0
                            [ga] => 
                            [gt] => REG
                        )

                )

            [7] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [eid] => 2014091406
                            [gsis] => 56193
                            [d] => Sun
                            [t] => 1:00
                            [q] => F
                            [h] => TEN
                            [hnn] => titans
                            [hs] => 10
                            [v] => DAL
                            [vnn] => cowboys
                            [vs] => 26
                            [rz] => 0
                            [ga] => 
                            [gt] => REG
                        )

                )

            [8] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [eid] => 2014091407
                            [gsis] => 56194
                            [d] => Sun
                            [t] => 1:00
                            [q] => F
                            [h] => WAS
                            [hnn] => redskins
                            [hs] => 41
                            [v] => JAC
                            [vnn] => jaguars
                            [vs] => 10
                            [rz] => 0
                            [ga] => 
                            [gt] => REG
                        )

                )

            [9] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [eid] => 2014091408
                            [gsis] => 56195
                            [d] => Sun
                            [t] => 4:05
                            [q] => F
                            [h] => SD
                            [hnn] => chargers
                            [hs] => 30
                            [v] => SEA
                            [vnn] => seahawks
                            [vs] => 21
                            [rz] => 0
                            [ga] => 
                            [gt] => REG
                        )

                )

            [10] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [eid] => 2014091409
                            [gsis] => 56196
                            [d] => Sun
                            [t] => 4:05
                            [q] => F
                            [h] => TB
                            [hnn] => buccaneers
                            [hs] => 17
                            [v] => STL
                            [vnn] => rams
                            [vs] => 19
                            [rz] => 0
                            [ga] => 
                            [gt] => REG
                        )

                )

            [11] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [eid] => 2014091410
                            [gsis] => 56197
                            [d] => Sun
                            [t] => 4:25
                            [q] => F
                            [h] => DEN
                            [hnn] => broncos
                            [hs] => 24
                            [v] => KC
                            [vnn] => chiefs
                            [vs] => 17
                            [rz] => 0
                            [ga] => 
                            [gt] => REG
                        )

                )

            [12] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [eid] => 2014091411
                            [gsis] => 56198
                            [d] => Sun
                            [t] => 4:25
                            [q] => F
                            [h] => GB
                            [hnn] => packers
                            [hs] => 31
                            [v] => NYJ
                            [vnn] => jets
                            [vs] => 24
                            [rz] => 0
                            [ga] => 
                            [gt] => REG
                        )

                )

            [13] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [eid] => 2014091412
                            [gsis] => 56199
                            [d] => Sun
                            [t] => 4:25
                            [q] => F
                            [h] => OAK
                            [hnn] => raiders
                            [hs] => 14
                            [v] => HOU
                            [vnn] => texans
                            [vs] => 30
                            [rz] => 0
                            [ga] => 
                            [gt] => REG
                        )

                )

            [14] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [eid] => 2014091413
                            [gsis] => 56200
                            [d] => Sun
                            [t] => 8:30
                            [q] => F
                            [h] => SF
                            [hnn] => 49ers
                            [hs] => 20
                            [v] => CHI
                            [vnn] => bears
                            [vs] => 28
                            [rz] => 0
                            [ga] => 
                            [gt] => REG
                        )

                )

            [15] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [eid] => 2014091500
                            [gsis] => 56201
                            [d] => Mon
                            [t] => 8:30
                            [q] => P
                            [h] => IND
                            [hnn] => colts
                            [hs] => 0
                            [v] => PHI
                            [vnn] => eagles
                            [vs] => 0
                            [rz] => 0
                            [ga] => 
                            [gt] => REG
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I tried this foreach but it output nothing:

```
foreach ($nfl->g as $game) {
    print '<pre>';
    print_r($game); 
    print '</pre>';
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$nfl->g` doesn't exist and you also need to grab the attributes and not the contents since they are all blank. You should have success with the following. Note the proper depth in the XML `$nfl->gms->g`. Also note the use of the `attributes()` call.

```
$nfl = simplexml_load_file('http://www.nfl.com/liveupdate/scorestrip/ss.xml');

print '<pre>';
foreach ($nfl->gms->g as $game) {
    foreach($game->attributes() as $a => $b) {
        echo $a,'="',$b,"\"\n";
    }
    echo "\n------------------------------------------\n";
}
print '</pre>';
```

Comment: Where did you get `$nfl->gms` from?